# Variable to be passed to multiple views using the _layout page

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Does anyone know of a way to pass a variable so that all views  have access to that variable?

I would like my app to allow a user to select a year from a drop down list which will then be used by different views as a global variable. This is to save records associated to that particular year.

I have tried using a session variable as such

Controller:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vm.years.Count; i++)
{
    Session.Add(vm.years[i].StartDate.Year + "/" + vm.years[i].EndDate.Year, vm.years[i].Id);
}
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<select class="float-right">
@foreach (var a in Session)
{
    <option value="@a">@a</option>
}                 
</select>
```

However, this does not seem to be the best way to do it as if you refresh the page you lose the session variables and if you change pages the value is changed back to the first value in the drop down list.

Would I be better off using a partial view with a model and render the partial view in the _layout page?

Comment: "if you refresh the page you lose the session variables"...er, no, persisting between page refreshes is the whole point of a session variable. "if you change pages the value is changed back to the first value in the drop down list." - you need to write your dropdownlist in such as way that it sets the "selected" attribute on the option(s) which correspond to the current session variable value(s) (if any).

Comment: P.S. you'd be better using a single session variable which is an array. Then in your view you'd fetch the array from the session, and loop through the array, instead of the whole Session collection. Right now, if you add any _other_ variables to your session as part of a future enhancement, they'll get caught up in your foreach loop, with no way of telling which variable is related to your dropdownlist, and which is for something else.

Comment: @ADyson for some reason when i did a hard refresh it got rid of the session variables seems to be fine now. So you are saying that a session variable would still be the best way to go about this?

Comment: " if you do a hard refresh you lose the session variable" I've never encountered that problem. Are you using cookies? Are you sure you don't just have a very short session timeout or something?

Comment: Ignore that seems to be working fine earlier I was testing and done a hard refresh and the variables had disappeared. That doesn't occur now may have been something I had done wrong.

Comment: ok well then apart from my caveat about using a single session variable, your approach is basically fine

Comment: @ADyson I will take the single session variable in to account thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the suggestion in to account from ADyson the solution I got working was as follows.

Controller: stores the years in a list of strings which then gets stored in the single Session variable years.

```
List<string> years = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < vm.taxYears.Count; i++)
{
     years.Add(vm.taxYears[i].StartDate.Year + "/" + vm.taxYears[i].EndDate.Year);
}

Session["years"] = years;
```

View: assign the variable years from the session variables as a list of strings and loop through them to get all the years as options.

```
@{ 
    var years = Session["years"] as List<string>;
}

<select id="yearSelect" class="float-right custom-select" onchange="storeYear(this.value)">
   @foreach (var a in years)
   {
       <option value="@a">@a</option>
   }
</select>
```

Javascript: store the value in a localStorage so that when you change to a different page the value selected stays the same.

```
function storeYear(yearVal) {
   var currentVal = document.getElementById("yearSelect").value;
   localStorage.setItem('selectVal', currentVal);
   location.reload();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    if (localStorage.selectVal) {  
        //Select the value stored
         $("#yearSelect").val(localStorage.selectVal);
    }
});
```